# Layered navigation not showing properly, need correct code for layout.xml

Tags: xml, magento-1.9

I want my layered navigation to show at the left of all of the category pages and on the left of the search results page. At first it wasn't appearing whatsoever so edited the layout.xml file inserting the following code:

`<reference name="left">
     <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
 </reference>`

I then got the following results:

[image: Result]

Any idea how to make the layered navigation display correctly on the left side of the search and category pages?

Thanks